# CSS: DIVs overlaping, z-index doesn't fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

This is my html:

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="body-inner">
    <div class="game" id="csgo" onclick="window.location='https://csgo.fraid.gg/'"><div class="game-handle"></div></div>
    <div class="game" id="minecraft" onclick="window.location='https://mc.fraid.gg/'"><div class="game-handle"></div></div>
    <div class="game" id="lineage" onclick="window.location='https://l2.fraid.gg/'"><div class="game-handle"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.game {
  width: 807px;
  height: 607px;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 32px black) opacity(50%) grayscale(80%);
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: -220px;
  margin-right: -220px;
  transform: scale(0.7,0.7);
  transition: 150ms ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
.game#csgo {
  background: url('game-csgo.png') no-repeat rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  background-size: 100%;
}
.game#minecraft {
  background: url('game-minecraft.png') no-repeat rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  background-size: 100%;
}
.game#lineage {
  background: url('game-l2.png') no-repeat rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  background-size: 100%;
}
.game.hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 64px black) opacity(100%) grayscale(0%);
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transition: 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.game-handle {
  width: 411px;
  height: 525px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 198px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

jQuery script to toggle .hover class:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.game-handle').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.game').addClass('hover',0);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.game').removeClass('hover',0);
  });
});
```

And the thing is that the RED parts are the things that I want to register mouseover events with. But the divs next to the previous ones, going from left-to-right, overlap the RED areas too! :( The GREEN parts are the divs holding the backgrounds itself. Any idea how to bring all the RED divs into the absolute front?

(The only reason why I do this this way is because the custommer wants to have "cards" that have thing hanging from them like the sword,gun,arm and stuff, and then the main div has to be bigger in width and have negative margin from both sides)

Screen:

[image]

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9yy2csvd/

The Problem:

[image]

cursor is on the red part but the green from div on the right overlaps it (no mouseenter event triggered). So you have to go more to the left with cursor so you only touch the red part (and trigger the event). But I need it that the red part is on top of all the green,

Each background of divs with class .game look like this:

[image]

I need that only when I move the mouse cursor over the "card" itself, not the transparent background around it (including parts of the picture that are sticking out of the "card"), the event is triggered.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle, so people can help you easily.

Comment: When I mouseover the green section, nothing happens, it only zooms when I hit the red section. Is that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes, but the red section is overlaped by the green from the div on the right side of each one, and that mean you have to be in the 1/4 of the width of the red div inside in order to trigger the event.

Comment: @abeyaz gonna create the fiddle

Comment: Here u all go https://jsfiddle.net/9yy2csvd/

Comment: Your `.game` containers have `position:relative;z-index:99`, this creates a new stacking context. All elements inside the container will be flattened into one layer, and then the container and its contents are rendered together at `z-index:99`.

Comment: should I do x-index: 9999; on the .game-handle's with !important variable then?

Comment: removing the z-index: 99; from .game does no change :/

Comment: Based on what I see in the fiddle, the hover **is** only seen on the red areas. I don't understand the issue at all.

Comment: @Scott I updated the issue and added a new picture, hope you will understand now, sorry for not understanding the issue, I'm not that good in explaining

Comment: if you change game-hover to game:hover, you accomplish what you have without using code

Comment: @Bindrid Yes, but the divs are 807px wide, and still overlap, and I don't want to point the cursor anywhere around the "cards" itself and still trigger the event which increases their size. I had it like that before, but I only want to trigger scale change when the use points the cursor on the middle (the red area - the acctual card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated.

## When `z-index` typically works?

`z-index` works inside a scope of closest parent with `z-index`. In other words, you can never have child higher then other parents when if this child's parent has set `z-index`.

## The chase

From my personal tests I concluded that you indeed **can** achieve desired effect, as long as you will **not use any of the following**:

1. Any `z-index` for parent
2. Any `transform` for parent
3. Any `filter` for parent

Turns out every property from the list above will **break** the result.

## Example

There're many variables for when `z-index` works or doesn't work as you'd expect. I prepared a test environment for you to try out. Notice when it breaks and what property you can apply to fix it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').addClass('child-relative'); // Simplest combination when it works
  
  $('label input').click(function() {
    var className = $(this).data('class');
    $('body').toggleClass(className);
  }).each(function() {
    var className = $(this).data('class');
    $(this).attr({
      checked: $('body').hasClass(className)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/*/ "Works" = .child is above all .parent-s /*/

/*/ Basic styles /*/
.parent {
  outline: 2px dotted blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.child {
  background: yellow;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
}

/*/ Variables /*/
.parent-relative .parent {
  /* Works when .child has position: relative/absolute; AND z-index > 0 */
  position: relative;
}

.parent-z-index .parent {
  /* Never works */
  z-index: 0;
}

.parent-transform .parent {
  /* Never works */
  transform: scale(1);
}

.parent-transform-rotate .parent {
  /* Never works */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.parent-filter .parent {
  /* Never works */
  filter: opacity(100%);
}

.child-relative .child {
  /* Works when .parent has only position: static; OR when .child has z-index as well */
  position: relative;
}

.child-z-index .child {
  /* Works when .parent has position: static; OR position: relative; WITHOUT z-index */
  z-index: 1;
}

.child-transform .child {
  /* Doesn't matter */
  transform: scale(1);
}

.child-transform-rotate .child {
  /* Doesn't matter */
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.child-filter .child {
  /* Doesn't matter */
  filter: opacity(100%);
}

/*/ Ignore following code /*/
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.parent {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.controls .bad {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2><code>.parent { }</code></h2>
<div class="controls">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="parent-relative">
    <code>position: relative;</code>
  </label>
  <label class="bad">
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="parent-z-index">
    <code>z-index: 0;</code>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <label class="bad">
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="parent-transform">
    <code>transform: scale(1);</code>
  </label>
  <label class="bad">
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="parent-transform-rotate">
    <code>rotate: scale(360deg);</code>
  </label>
  <label class="bad">
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="parent-filter">
    <code>filter: opacity(100%);</code>
  </label>
</div>
<h2><code>.child { }</code></h2>
<div class="controls">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="child-relative">
    <code>position: relative;</code>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="child-z-index">
    <code>z-index: 1;</code>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="child-transform">
    <code>transform: scale(1);</code>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="child-transform-rotate">
    <code>rotate: scale(360deg);</code>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="child-filter">
    <code>filter: opacity(100%);</code>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that I have tested this only in Chrome on Windows. Perhaps in other environments properties marked as `.bad` will work without issue. I'll leave detailed tests for you to perform! ;-)

*Have a nice day!

~Wiktor*

Comment: Thank you very much! Using this I found out that the transform: scale(1); breaks the thing. But I need some kind of a way to scale the entire thing down and then the desired one up.

Comment: Perhaps you can use old-school `width` and `height` with some addition of clever used `margin` or `position`. I'm not entirely sure, but it may be worth asking separate scaling-related question if you encounter further problems.

Comment: Thank you for help! Have a nice day too!